# HTML JavaScript variable data-percent attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the data-percent attribute but I need it to be variable. I'm using JavaScript to get data from a text file and need to insert that into the data-percent value

it would be nice to do this

```
 data-percent=".change"
```

or

```
 $('#test').attr('data-percent', '.change');
```

Here's what I'm working with

```
 <div class="wrap">

     <div class="holder">
       <div id="test" class="one" data-percent="85%"><span class="label">one</span>
       </div>
     </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">                                                             
     setTimeout(function start() {

       $('.bar').each(function (i) {
       var $bar = $(this);
       $(this).append('<span class="count"></span>')
       setTimeout(function () {
        $bar.css('width', $bar.attr('data-percent'));
        }, i * 100);
       });

        $('.count').each(function () {
       $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).parent('.bar').attr('data-percent')
    }, {
        duration: 2000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now) + '%');
        }
    });
});

}, 500)

    </script>                                           
</div>
```

Here is the javascript where i get data from text file. This is the data i need to replace the static data-percent value with

```
    var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
     XHR.open("GET", "file.txt", true);
     XHR.send();
     XHR.onload = function (){
     var change = document.getElementById("one").innerHTML = ( XHR.responseText.slice(6, XHR.responseText.indexOf("\n")) );
     };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getElementById is called with a parameter which actually points to the css class ('one')

Change this line :

```
var change = document.getElementById("one").innerHTML = ( XHR.responseText.slice(6, XHR.responseText.indexOf("\n")) );
```

To this :

```
var change = XHR.responseText.slice(6, XHR.responseText.indexOf("\n"));
$('#test').attr('data-percent', change);
$('.label').text(change); // to display the value in span
```

Comment: thanks for responding. That code changes the labels. Ive been playing with it and cant get it to work. The only code that seems to actually change the percent value is this:    $('#test').attr('data-percent', '55%');  but again it only changes it with a static value i need something like    $('#test').attr('data-percent', '.change');    Thank you again

Comment: What do you mean with '.change'. What does the dot stand for?

Comment: I'm sorry that was my ignorance coming out you nailed it the first time thanks a bunch.